# Identical HTML code read differently using python

Tags: python, html, csv

excuse the amateurish code, I'm sure it's painful to look at for anyone with experience.

I'm trying to write some code that is able to save all the data on from the following link:
 http://pq.gov.mt/pqweb.nsf/bysitting?openview, and save them in an easily searchable csv file.

The code I have written seems to work fine, in that it manages to save all the information I need in different columns of an csv file. It all breaks down however when it reaches one question, 412 on this page: http://pq.gov.mt/PQWeb.nsf/bysitting!OpenView&Start=1&Count=20&Expand=9#9, where it fails to register the last entry for some reason (marked with an arrow <<<<<-----).

As far as I can tell, the html for the page is identical to the rest, which all seem to work fine so I can't really understand how or why it is different.

Not sure how well I've explained my problem but would be happy to elaborate if  necessary.

Thanks in advance. Code below

```
 for item in html_search_1:
    x = item.find_all('a',href = True)

    for t in x:
        store = []
        y = t.get('href')
        new_url = ("http://pq.gov.mt"+y)
        page_2 = urllib.request.urlopen(new_url).read()
        soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(page_2, 'html.parser')
        html_search_3 = soup_2.find_all("div", class_ = "col-md-10") 
        for ccc in html_search_3:
            html_search_4 = ccc.find_all("div", class_ = "row")
            for haga in html_search_4:
                    z = haga.find_all("div", class_ = ["col-md-2","col-md-4","col-md-12","col-md-10"])

                    for new_item in z:
                        store.append(new_item.text)

    var0 = 1 
    var1 = 3 
    var2 = 5
    var3 = 7 
    var4 = 9
    var5 = 13 
    var6 = 14
    var7 = 15
    var8 = 17
    count = 1   
    for o in range(1):  
        try: 

            legislature.append(store[var0])
            category.append(store[var1])
            question_number.append(store[var2])
            date.append(store[var3])
            sitting.append(store[var4])
            title.append(store[var5])
            MPs.append(store[var6])
            question.append(store[var7])
            print(store[var7])
            answer.append(store[var8])
            print(store[var8]) #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------------


            var0 = var0 + 19
            var1 = var1 + 19
            var2 = var2 + 19
            var3 = var3 + 19
            var4 = var4 + 19
            var5 = var5 + 19
            var6 = var6 + 19
            var7 = var7 + 19
            var8 = var8 + 19


        except:
            pass
```

Comment: You're setting `store = []` each time through the `for t in x` loop. So it will only contain the values from the last item in `x`.

Comment: Maybe there's an exception: can you `raise` instead of `pass` to see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was an interesting question. Took me a while to grasp your intent, especially as my knowledge of Maltesian language is limited :-), but I think I got a solution. Never mind amateur code, you tried and you thought about the problem. My code may not win an adward also, but I get over your question *412* without problems.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

div_index = {'legislature': (0, 'md4'),
             'category': (1, 'md4'),
             'qnumber': (2, 'md4'),
             'qdate': (3, 'md4'),
             'sitting': (4, 'md4'),
             'title': (3, 'md10'),
             'mps': (0, 'md12'),
             'question': (1, 'md12'),
             'answer': (3, 'md12')}

def process_file(urlstring):
    r = requests.get("http://pq.gov.mt/" + urlstring)
    data = r.content
    doc = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    divs = {}
    divs['md2'] = doc.find_all("div", class_ = ["col-md-2"])
    divs['md4'] = doc.find_all("div", class_ = ["col-md-4"])
    divs['md10'] = doc.find_all("div", class_ = ["col-md-10"])
    divs['md12'] = doc.find_all("div", class_ = ["col-md-12"])

    result = {}
    for key, index in div_index.items():
        result[key] = divs[index[1]][index[0]].text

    return result


def main():
    r = requests.get('http://pq.gov.mt/PQWeb.nsf/bysitting!OpenView&Start=1&Count=20&Expand=9#9')
    data = r.content
    doc = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    links = doc.find_all("a")
    for link in links:
        if 'href' in link.attrs and link.attrs['href'].find('!OpenDocument') > 0:
            result = process_file(link.attrs['href'])
            print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I do, is first store the index for each fields in a dictionary, along with the class of the `div` I am interested in. After I groked the structure of the page, I found it easier to parse a list for every class. That way it's easy to find the data (web scraping being what it is, you always have to manually follow if they change the page structure, so this was not a concern for me, having a more readable code however was).

The advantage is that by using the enumeration of the dict keys and values I could remove more than two dozen lines form my prototype code. This way the code just loops over every entry in my index dict and retrieves the text for each dic.

I created a function for each detail URL and cleaned up the code a little, as well as returning a dictionary for convenience. If you want to split the names of the MP as individual lines, you still have to use `.split("\n")` on the `result['mps']`. Hope that helps ...

Comment: Hey Arminius, sorry only just getting a chance to have a look at this. Thank you so much, this has definitely saved me a lot of time - doubt I would have managed. 

The code looks a lot better and less cumbersome and from the looks of it, I just need to add a couple of lines to save to a csv and I'm done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but I'll post it anyway:

You could reduce your code by very much by replacing this syntax below:

```
var0 = 1 
var1 = 3 
var2 = 5

var0 += 19
...
```

with

```
import numpy as np
index = np.array([1,3,5,7])  # we store indexes in a numpy array instead
#index[0] = 1

index += 19 # this will add 19 to all elements creating [20,22,24,26]
#cols[0] = 20
```